# How to convert a single char into NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, nsstring

I know how to convert a 'C' style string into a `NSString`, but is there an elegant (or even just easy!) way of converting a single 'C' char into a single character `NSString`?

I.e. 'Z' -> @"Z"

Short of creating a char *string and setting `string[0] = myChar` and then using

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:string]
```

I can't see a better way.

Comment: Why should a string with length 1 be any different from a string with length 2 or 3? What's wrong with `@"Z"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", myChar]`

Comment: Easy and elegant! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
char myChar = 'r';
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , myChar];
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution (just for fun!), using a C99 ["Compound Literal"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)
with a Objective-C ["Boxed Expression"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
char myChar = 'A';
NSString *string = @((char[]){myChar, 0});
```